# Error while loading shared libraries:

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

After installation version 1.3 when I am trying to run the program with command ; `gazebo`

I am getting the following error :

gazebo: error while loading shared libraries: libgazebo_common.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Please suggest what to do now....

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1071/error-while-loading-shared-libraries:/) by [amit](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/166/amit/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 17 on 2013-01-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/164/boris/) on 2013-01-27**:
Please provide some details -- installation method (binary/source), output of `locate libgazebo_common.so` and `env | grep -i gazebo`. Though, it may be sufficient to run `sudo ldconfig` in some cases...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Looks like some environment variables are missing/wrong. In case you didn't change the `CMAKE_INSTALLATION_PREFIX` you have to source the `setup.sh` file from `/usr/local/share/gazebo-1.4/`. If `gazebo` is installed in another folder, then you need to add the following lines to your `.bashrc`:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<install_path>/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PATH=&lt;install_path&gt;/local/bin:$PATH
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=<install_path>/local/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH
source <install_path>/share/gazebo-1.4/setup.sh
```

where `<install_path>` is the same with `CMAKE_INSTALLATION_PREFIX` specified during build configuration (see [Step 10](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/1.3/install#Compiling_From_Source) in Wiki). After that reopen the terminal or manualy source the `.bashrc` with

`$ source .bashrc`

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/164/boris/) with karma: 330 on 2013-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [amit](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/166/amit/) on 2013-01-27**:
Thank you very much ... I finally solved the probelm.

**Comment by [amit](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/166/amit/) on 2013-01-27**:
But when I close the terminal and try to launch gazebo again I get the same error message. So each time I have to source it. Since I am using the default directory /usr/local , I use the 2nd command given in Step 10 in wiki. How can I get this solved ?

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/164/boris/) on 2013-01-27**:
Simply add `source /usr/local/share/gazebo-1.4/setup.sh` to the end of your `~/.bashrc` file.

**Comment by [amit](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/166/amit/) on 2013-01-27**:
Alright ... thanks again.

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/164/boris/) on 2013-01-28**:
Please also consider to mark the answer as correct if it did help you :)

**Comment by [Hugo Siles](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/369/hugo-siles/) on 2013-06-11**:
I also have the same problem, this the location of my instalation files LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/gazebo-1.8/plugins:/usr/local/lib/gazebo-1.8/plugins:
GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH=/usr/local/share/gazebo-1.8:/usr/local/share/gazebo_models
GAZEBO_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11345
GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/local/lib/gazebo-1.8/plugins
GAZEBO_MODEL_DATABASE_URI=http://gazebosim.org/models I have followed the answer but I still get the error: gazebo: error while loading shared libraries: libgazebo_com

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/164/boris/) on 2013-06-12**:
@Hugo Siles, please create a new question, so the others can see it quickly. Otherwise only those to participate in the discussion here will be notified. P.S. a similar question was recently asked [here](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3189/linking-problem-when-compiling-from-source/).